# How to make a T-SQL query where the first letter of the output equals to a character

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I would like to know if there is a way to make a query where the output is stored in a local variable and IF condition is used to check if the first character if the output matches to a character

Query outline :-

```
DECLARE @result;
SET @result=SELECT @@version;
SELECT * FROM @result IF(SUBSTRING(@result, 1, 1)='M') WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:3'
```

Comment: Why have you tagged 2 completed unsupported versions of SQL Server? 2005 has been usupported for years, and 2008's been unsupported since mid last year. You *really* should have been looking at upgrade paths awhile ago.

Comment: Many, many people still use unsupported versions of SQL Server for reasons out of their control or at least Compatibility Levels for compatibility reasons @Larnu.  Comments such as yours are seldom helpful and generally contribute to the pereption of there being a hostile environment on SO.

Comment: Many people are still using unsupported versions, yes @iamdave , but many seem to also be oblivious of the fact that they are unsupported. Also, it seems odd that the OP has tagged not 1 version of SQL Server, but 2; both of which are unsupported. My comment, however, is in no way hostile, it's a recommendation that the OP should really be looking at the version of SQL Server they are using and seeing what they can do about upgrading, or prompting them that they have used the wrong tags. 2005 and 2008 both lack a lot of functionality that we take for granted in supported versions.

Comment: Well at least one person (ie: me) read it as hostile @Larnu, so I would assume there are others that do too.

Comment: I can assure you, it isn't, @iamdave .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a *type* for the local variable, perhaps `nvarchar(max)` (since [`@@version` is defined as `nvarchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/version-transact-sql-configuration-functions)) - and since that is not a table variable, you can't select *from* it - but you can select *it*:

```sql
DECLARE @result nvarchar(max);
SET @result = @@version;
SELECT @result;
```

or on more recent SQL Server versions:

```sql
DECLARE @result nvarchar(max) = @@version;
SELECT @result;
```

as for the if test:

```sql
IF(SUBSTRING(@result, 1, 1)='M') WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03';
```

however, this (`WAITFOR DELAY`) seems like a very odd thing to do... and note that because of how TDS works, you usually won't see any results from the query until *after* the delay has passed.

Comment: Hi Marc,
I need the waitfor delay function can you give me the exact query

Comment: @Rahul what part of the code I've already shown doesn't work? it works fine here...

Comment: Thanks Marc ,Worked like a charm